# Представить данные в виде структуры дерева

Tags: android, структуры

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся данные о родословной. Типа представить рода, его дети, дети детей и т.д. Можно ли как-то представить эти данные в виде структуры дерева как на картинке. Хотелось бы для опыта написать приложение на Android для составления древа семейного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `onDraw` для этих целей. Так как вы сможете полностью все что нужно рисовать самостоятельно. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) документация.

Есть вариант и попроще - использовать [библиотеку](https://github.com/naman14/AlgorithmVisualizer-Android):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или [вот](https://github.com/Team-Blox/GraphView) еще библиотека есть по построению дерева. Любой вариант поможет вам достичь нужного результата. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867939/how-to-create-a-family-tree-structure) еще вопрос прям по созданию дерева семьи, может поможет.

Вопрос только в эффективности и скорости реализации. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо большое буду изучать)